# MYSQL Storage for Query Results

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain how does the storage works in MySQL. For example if i have a very large data set in my DB, what happens each time i give the query - SELECT * FROM option? Does querying this statement use up the memory in the drive?

Comment: Does querying this statement use up the memory in the drive? - sometimes , if runs out of ram.. WHy do you ask?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.